# Where can I find a list of interesting websites/blogs in French, for like science, philosophy, entertainment, etc?

Tags: ressources

I'm learning French.  I've looked at suggestions and people usually suggest like newspapers, news videos, or funny youtube stuff.  I'm tired of looking at newspaper websites and videos, I don't care about politics at all.  I don't watch much youtube either.

But I go to college and I take courses in philosophy, in arts, and in social sciences.  Is there like a list of popular blogs or sites in French, like latest scientific findings, or ones about literature and philosophy, about latest entertainment like movies and so on?  I'm just looking to find something that I enjoy reading, so I can learn French that way.

merci

Comment: Not really an answer but to have the plot and comments about new movies, you can go on [allocine](http://www.allocine.fr/film/fichefilm_gen_cfilm=194075.html).

Comment: I don't know of any list like that, but if you're looking for funny sciency stuff, you should take a look at "Tu mourras moins bête" (You'll die less dumb), there's a [webcomic](http://tumourrasmoinsbete.blogspot.fr/) and [videos](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCKtG_lXZk4pRJkapfK0eprA).

Comment: How good are you at understanding spoken French ? I have a lot of funny and/or interesting youtube channels to recommend, but they're not all easy to understand.

Comment: On top of my head, I'd recommend Science Etonnante. He has a youtube channel about science, it's pretty interesting and he's very easy to understand (compared to other youtubers). He also makes written posts with each video, going further into detail.

Answer (score 2):

A good way to find a blog in a particular language is to google it in the language.

Want a French chemistry forum? "**Forums sur la chimie**"

What about philosophy?
"**forums sur la philosophie**"

Comment: If you liked my answer make sure to mark it as an answer

Comment: I did like your answer but I do prefer if someone can give me a series of links to reputable websites.  It's hard for read French and so searching for these terms and reading through all those results is not easy, but harder still is evaluating if any are good.